# Is it possible to get all facebook checkins of user's friend list through facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-checkins

I need all of the facebook checkins made by friend list of a user through facebook api. I am not able to get any proper documention for this.

Comment: No it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

looks like they dont offer it anymore

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/checkins

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but the Graph query you were looking for is `/me/friends?fields=tagged_places`.